# Wordpress Page Doesn't update on Initial Load

Tags: html, wordpress, https

I have a wordpress site: carlscholl.com

I am running into a problem where the homepage is not updating when I initially go to the address. Here is a screenshot of the initial loading of my site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZiE0.jpg

Here is another screen shot when I refresh the page. As you can see, I removed the picture of the piggy bank causing the site to be insecure. I replaced it with same image as the other post.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx9CK.jpg

Does anyone know why the site is not updating when I initially go to it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to DNS for the domain or caching. After looking into your website, I did not find any image at the moment, however, I noticed that your website is loading from Cloudflare. Usually, Cloudflare caches the images so, even if you remove it from the website, it can take some time for it to be gone. However, you can still clear the cache from the Cloudflare Dashboard by the "Purge Cache" option.
Another thing that I noticed that your website is not automatically redirecting to https:// by default. As you mentioned "removing the piggy bank image caused the site to insure", it might not be the case and you can enable auto SSL redirection from the Cloudflare Dashboard > SSL/TLS > Edge Certificates > Always Use HTTPS
So basically, the site not updating or the image not loading issue should be resolved automatically after some time or you can purge the cache for that image specifically (from Cloudflare) to speed it up.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I updated the cloudfare and its secure now. However, another problem I am having is when I upload a new post or remove a post, the live site is not getting updated. I have tried purging all the caches, and nothing happens. Do you know what the cause is?

Comment: Hey Carl, Raisul said "Usually, Cloudflare caches the images so, even if you remove it from the website, it can take some time for it to be gone.", this applies to everything, even adding new content.